# asymptotic behavior of the pdf constraints due to Roger Lee

Tags: implied-volatility, moments

In a beautiful paper, [http://math.uchicago.edu/~rl/moment.pdf](http://math.uchicago.edu/%7Erl/moment.pdf), Roger Lee (2004) shows that implied variance is bounded above by a function linear in the log-strike k.

Does anybody know how it translate for the pdf $f$ or cdf $F$ of the spot if we suppose that $f(x) \sim_{+\infty} \beta / x^\alpha$

Thank you